# Is there a way to invoke the Azure CLI in an Azure Function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cli

As opposed to writing an Azure Function in C# or JS, I'd like to write a Azure Function that runs azure cli commands.
How would I go about doing that?

Comment: AFAIK, these are the Supported languages in Azure Functions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/supported-languages

Answer (score 0):

As Ashok mentioned, Azure function does not support Azure CLI now.At present, there are several Generally available and experimental languages in Azure Function V1, and preview languages in V2.

You could see the  [Azure roadmap](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/roadmap/?tag=functions) fo find information about planned changes to language support. If you want Azure Function supports CLI command, This is the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions).

Answer (score 0):

C# and Javascript are the only non-experimental languages at the moment. If you are looking to automate Azure operations, have you looked at Azure Automation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-intro